# Spring MVC from:select with multiple options and at least one option selected

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form:select that is populated using enum values and I want to make sure that at least one of the options is selected (the user is not allowed to deselect all).

```
<form:select path="statusArray" id="status" multiple="true">
  <form:options items="${availableStatuses}" itemLabel="displayName" itemValue="value"/>
</form:select>
```

How can I do that ?

Note: I am fairly new to Spring MVC and to web development in general.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change variables to yours, its working staff below:

```
<select th:field="*{percentage}">
    <option th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, 100)}" th:value="${i}" th:text="${i}" 
      th:selected="${i==75}"></option>
</select>
```

[more info here](https://%3Cselect%20th:field=%22*%7Bpercentage%7D%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Coption%20th:each=%22i%20:%20$%7B#numbers.sequence(0,%20100)%7D%22%20th:value=%22$%7Bi%7D%22%20th:text=%22$%7Bi%7D%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20th:selected=%22$%7Bi==75%7D%22%3E%3C/option%3E%20%3C/select%3E)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think spring mvc provides the feature to get selected one or more options in `<form:select` while rendering the view, But one work around is using JSTL condition tag you can achieve it.

Below example shows you how to make selected the options whose value 1 or 3:

```
<form:select path="statusArray" id="status" multiple="true">        
    <c:forEach items="${availableStatuses}" var="opt">
    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${opt.value eq 1 or opt.value eq 3}">
        <option value="${opt.value}"
            selected="selected"><c:out value="${opt.displayName}"/></option>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
        <option value="${opt.value}"><c:out value="${opt.displayName}"/></option>
      </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>                     
   </c:forEach>             
</form:select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. hmm maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I am able to select few entries using spring mvc but what I want is to make sure that the user cannot deselect all. I want at least one option to be selected at all times.